# Ruby Sinatra running in AWS Lambda not connecting to RDS Postgres

Tags: ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm trying to run a Ruby Sinatra app with a Postgres DB in AWS Lambda and RDS.

The app can connect from the local dev environment to the RDS database but I get this error message when the app is running in AWS Lambda and tries to access the RDS db:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished - connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
:
/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:80:in `rescue in new_client'
```

Any idea where should I look at? Is this an issue with the pg gem not being properly packed? Or VPC even when both the Lambda function and the RDS db are accessible from internet?

Thanks!

Edit:
database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test

development:
  <<: *default
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: The fact that the error message asks "Is the server running locally" suggests that you're trying to connect to PostgreSQL locally (on the same machine as the Lambda function is running). Check your connect string/parameters to ensure you are connecting to the correct IP of the RDS PostgreSQL instance (and that is not local to the Lambda function).

Comment: Have you created the correct IAM execution role for Lambda to connect to RDS?

Comment: @ClintonBosch, I haven't and I'll try to find out documentation about it. But is that necessary? The RDS is not restricted network-wise. It can be accessed through internet just fine. The same goes for the Lambda function. Thanks!

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the insight. The database.yml (Added to the main question) has the correct values passed with env variables. I've checked that the values are correct. Should I be connecting to the DB differently?

Comment: The error message clearly states it is trying to connect to a local database socket. It is not trying to go over the network to connect to a remote server at all. Perhaps you should add some debug logs to your Lambda function to print out the DB connection values. I think it may not be using the `development` settings when it runs in the Lambda environment.

Comment: @ClintonBosch the IAM execution role, which gives the Lambda function access to the AWS API, seems entirely irrelevant here.

Comment: Worth adding your code that's making the PostgreSQL connection (calling `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`?) and include logs of the relevant configuration values passed to that call, e.g. `:host`, `:adapter` etc.

Comment: @jarmod, according to [this documentation](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-recipes/blob/master/databases/postgresql-activerecord.md) I'm using the config/database.yml document to connect to the db. Isn't that enough?

Comment: As far as I can see, you haven't provided evidence that your code is trying to connect to the correct DB host. The symptoms suggest you may be trying to connect to localhost so to rule that out, I'm suggesting that you log the relevant parameter values right before your code creates a connection to the DB. Also, check if CloudWatch Logs show your Lambda function timing out.

Comment: It seems that the ENV variables in the `database.yml` file are not being resolved by ERB when the AWS Lambda function execute the code. If I literally set the values instead of using ENV variables and ran the Lambda function, then it works fine. 
The ENV variables are being passed to the app but not being resolved in the ERB code. 
The only difference is that locally I run the app with `rackup`, while the lambda function does it with the line 22 of [this file](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-sinatra-sample/blob/master/lambda.rb).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when the program ran from the AWS Lambda Function it wasn't resolving the erb sections of the `database.yml` file.

It was solved after adding this line in the `config.ru` file:

```rb
set :database, YAML.safe_load(ERB.new(File.read('./config/database.yml')).result(binding), aliases: true)
```